# Optimization Tab didn't appears on Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, experience-optimization

I'm experimenting with the issue where I have active all the content testing features, but on the Experience editor, I'm not seeing the optimization tab to control my tests

This is how I'm seeing:

[image]

And this is how I expected to see:

[image]

Does anyone know where I should grab the item to configure this correctly?

Regards,
Sergio Parissi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Sitecore Managed Cloud, then there is a known issue with the missing Optimization strip. Provided that you have enabled `xDB.Enabled`, `xDB.Tracking.Enabled` and `ContentTesting.Enabled` settings, you can just package those missing content items from another Sitecore instance and install it.

You can refer [here](https://www.nehemiahj.com/2022/02/sitecore-managed-cloud-app-service.html) for more details about the known issue.

Comment: Thanks! that package solved my problem!

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it solved your issue.